# Oil rig real-time data processing, waves/tides elimination

Tags: filters

I was asked to find a way to analyse/process a particular set of data collected by oil drilling rigs.

Among these real-time collected data we have the "mudflow", BUT, as the rig is floating it moves up and down due to waves and tides.

When the rig moves up the mudflow is slightly lower and when it moves down it's slightly higher.

I don't know which approach to choose to solve the problem and get rid of the "wave/tide" in the data collected to obtain a more accurate mudflow chart.

The person who gave me this task talked about Fourier transforms but I'm not sure if it's the right way to do after spending 2 days thinking/searching on this problem.

If you guys have a beginning of an answer it would be a great help for me.

Comment: What do you need to estimate? Is it that you need to find the true position of the rig?

Comment: I need to estimate the true behavior of the mudflow. For example if there is a small kick in the mud flow but this kick is compensated by a rising rig we may miss an important piece of information. It's also for a better presentation of the datas, instead of having a sinusoidal chart they want a flatter chart (if possible).

Comment: Could you post some of the data?  There may be some feature of the data that would make it possible to filter out just the mudflow.  Tides should be easy - just bandstop filter that removes the 12 hour 25 minute lunar tide cycle.  I don't know what else may be significant, but a look at the data might show something.

Comment: Just thought of something.  How often is the mudflow measured, and how accurately timed are the measurements?